# How to use Microsoft.Identity.Web for authorization for Azure.Storage.Blobs?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using *Microsoft.Identity.Web* (0.2.3-preview) for *OAuth* authentication with azure AD. I would like to achieve access to azure blob storage with *Azure.Storage.Blobs* (12.x).
I managed to find an example with *Azure.Storage.Blob* (11.x)

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation" };           
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
var tokencr = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
var storagecr = new StorageCredentials(tokencr);
var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(containerUri),storagecr);
```

where _tokenAcquisition is Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition obtained via constructor DI.

With *Blobs*(ver 12) I would like to use `BlobContainerClient(Uri blobContainerUri, Azure.Core.TokenCredential credential, Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClientOptions options = default)` instead of `CloudBlockBlob`, but I didn't manage to find any equivalent to `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth`(v11). The parameter `Azure.Core.TokenCredential` (`TokenCredential` parameter) doesn't seem to have any equivalent implementation.

**Is it possible to use Microsoft.Identity.Web for authorization for *Azure.Storage.Blobs*?**

**Note**
It is a research project not a production application.